# JSP after PUT request throws NPE

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jstl, put

I am using tomcat as my web server.

I define an error page in my `web.xml` file for 403 response codes.

This error page loads fine when I manually trigger it via a `GET` or `POST` `request`.
(ie: `response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);`)

I noticed via my logs (access logs and error logs), that when a client sends a `PUT` request, he gets a 403 response (which I understand is normal behavior).
However, for some reason, the jsp page that I defined in my `web.xml` file throws a `NullPointerException` when using one of `jstl/message` tags. eg:
`<fmt:message key="msgTitle" bundle="${msgBundle}"/>`

Is there any reason why it wouldn't be able to find the message when it loads the page after a `PUT` request but would not throw the exception when the page is loaded after a `GET` or `POST`?

Thanks.

Stacktrace of NPE:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.fmt.MessageSupport.doEndTag(MessageSupport.java:200)
        at org.apache.jsp.[filename]._jspx_meth_fmt_005fmessage_005f2([filename].java:602)
        at org.apache.jsp.[filename]._jspx_meth_fmt_005fbundle_005f0([filename].java:302)
        at org.apache.jsp.[filename]._jspx_meth_compress_005fhtml_005f0([filename].java:199)
        at org.apache.jsp.[filename]._jspService([filename].java:155)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
        ... 25 more
```

Comment: Please show us the stacktrace of NPE?

Comment: @KoheiTAMURA Added NPE stacktrace. Thanks.